# Failed submission of url to search engine sites

Tags: search-engines

How to submit free domain/url to search engine site if it's requiring you to add or upload html code but you cannot change or edit the page source?

Answer (score 1):

Webmaster Tools from Google as well as Bing allow you to upload a separate HTML file or add an identification string to your HTML `<head>` tag, to provide proof of ownership. If you are unable to do so, chances are, you do not own the domain in question and therefore have no businesses adding that domain to the Webmaster Tools, as it is quite uncommon not being able to add those things.